# Getting value from a console.log to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

The function I have written works fine and the value correctly writes to my terminal onSubmit, however I'm struggling to piece together why this code isn't updating my html.

```
router.post('/index', function(req, res, next) {

  // ...Get form values, do calculations to get toCost value.

      console.log('$' + toCost);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        var output = document.getElementById('cost');
        output.innerHTML = toCost;
      });

  res.location('/');
  res.redirect('/');
})
```

I receive the following error and jquery is loading fine.

```
$ is not defined
```

Admittedly this is an over-engineered node/express app. The code snippet lives wrapped in a route file, inside a post request.

How do I get my value onto the html?

Jade layout

```
extends layout

block content
  form(...)
  div#cost
```

Comment: `document` ready in Node.JS? I don't know much about NodeJS, but is it correct? There is no document in NodeJS...

Comment: Something strange is going on here? One can actually import jQuery into Node, but one can't use it like that, there's is no DOM to work with, so this seems just crazy?

Comment: Works fine for me as long as toCost is defined

Comment: i use this and it's pretty cool https://github.com/bahmutov/console-log-div

Comment: I think maybe just `res.send(toCost)` is what you really want

Comment: Hey Adeneo, would you be able to submit an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be as follows:

```
router.post('/index', function(req, res) {   <<< 'next' removed (only needed if using middleware)

  // ...Get form values, do calculations to get toCost value.

  console.log('$' + toCost);

  res.render('indexTemplate', {cost: toCost}); <<< pass toCost through to jade as 'cost'
});
```

Then in your jade file for the indexTemplate you can reference the 'cost' variable passed in like this:

indexTemplate.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  form(...)
  div#cost #{cost} <<< adds the cost variable to page
```

Then the value of toCost will appear in the resulting page.

No jQuery is required on the server side.

Comment: Awesome. That's the missing piece of the puzzle, thanks! Time to spend more time reading up on express.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is made for DOM manipulations and there's no DOM on a server.
Try using 'jsdom'.
jQuery is made for client side scripting, not for server-side client manipulations.

Comment: Best way to get my server-side value back to client-side?

Comment: Well, *"To use jQuery in Node, browser extensions, and other non-browser environments, use only 2.x releases. 1.x does not support these environments."* -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: jQuery does support running in Node

Comment: Best way - pass the value into a view to be rendered with the value you want to access, then use DOM client-side to access it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're trying to make changes on client-side from your backend. It doesn't work that way.

You could create a variable on backend for storing calculation result. And get this value by `get` query from client-side

Comment: That sounds like what I need to do, thanks. Could you provide a small example or point me to some readings?

Answer (score 1):

You're tring to reach DOM (that is on client side) from NodeJS on a server side. It doesn't work that way.